# C++ how to drag bitmap around screen

Tags: c++, bitmap, mouse, drag

Hi so I'm trying to make it so a little UFO bitmap (drawing/painting already taken care of) can be dragged around the screen. I can't seem to make the UFO position update and then redraw repeatedly from the MouseButtonDown() function (simplified code for mouse event handler). Any suggestions on detecting the dragging and redrawing accordingly? Code is below for relevant functions:

```
void MouseButtonDown(int x, int y, BOOL bLeft)
{
  if (bLeft)
  {
    while(_bMouseMoving == true && _bMouseDragRelease == false)  {  
        _iSaucerX = x - (_pSaucer->GetWidth() / 2);
        _iSaucerY = y - (_pSaucer->GetHeight() / 2);
        InvalidateRect(_pGame->GetWindow(), NULL, FALSE);
    }

        // Set the saucer position to the mouse position
        _iSaucerX = x - (_pSaucer->GetWidth() / 2);
        _iSaucerY = y - (_pSaucer->GetHeight() / 2);

  }
  else
  {
    // Stop the saucer
    _iSpeedX = 0;
    _iSpeedY = 0;
  }
}

void MouseButtonUp(int x, int y, BOOL bLeft)
{
    _bMouseDragRelease = true;
}

void MouseMove(int x, int y)
{
    _bMouseMoving = true;  
}
```

Comment: Your `MouseButtonDown` and `MouseMove` functions should be switched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clarify what chris said, you're only going to get the WM_xBUTTONDOWN message once, and you'll need to use that to toggle a dragging state that you can query when you recieve a WM_MOUSEMOVE message.

When you get the mouse move message during a dragging state, you'll want to invalidate the rectangle surrounding where the ufo was, and the rectangle surrounding where it is.

Invalidating a rectangle causes WM_PAINT messages, where you redraw whatever was behind the ufo, and the ufo in it's new place.

Or you could cheat and make the UFO a cursor when you're dragging :)